# Compatibility condition for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the following derivation, from G.B. Whitham's book *Linear and Nonlinear Waves*, 1999 (Chap. 13, p. 466).

[image]

The equations for $A$ are:
$$
A_x + 2\eta\eta_x=0 \qquad A_t + \eta\eta_x=0
$$
so I would integrate the equation on the left to:
$$
A = -\eta^2
$$
and I would rewrite the equation on the right to:
$$
A_t = \eta\eta_t
$$
which leads to
$$
A=\frac12 \eta^2.
$$
So how can these two equations be compatible? A similar doubt holds for $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the two equations to be compatible, i.e. the coefficients of the first order terms to be *equal* (not necessarily zero). Replacing all $t$ derivatives by minus the $x$ derivatives in the first order terms,
\begin{aligned}
A_x + 2\eta\eta_x &= A_t + \eta\eta_x \\
&= -A_x + \eta\eta_x \, ,
\end{aligned}
we get $2A_x + \eta\eta_x = 0$. Integrating with respect to $x$ gives $A = -\frac{1}{4}\eta^2$, since $A$ is a function of $\eta$ and its $x$ derivatives only.

The derivation for $B$ is similar.

Comment: I see, thank you. But how can be justified the fact that $A_t=-A_x$? I don't think that this hypothesis is made explicit in the book.

Comment: @J.D. This is due to the fact that $A(\eta,\eta_x,\dots )$ is a function of $\eta$ and its $x$ derivatives. Indeed, $A_t = \eta_t \partial_\eta A + \eta_{xt} \partial_{\eta_x} A + \dots$. From $\eta_t=-\eta_x$, we conclude that $A_t = -\eta_x \partial_\eta A - \eta_{xx} \partial_{\eta_x} A + \dots = -A_x$.